# Select DIV by button using JQuery

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I have two DIV tags namely respond-1 and respond-2. I want to select these divs with buttons. When i click respond1Button it should display respond-1 div and similarly on clicking of repond2Button, respond-2 div will be displayed.

By default page should display respond-1 div.

Comment: could you post some of your html?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For a HTML like below,

```
<div id="container">
    <div id="respond-1" class="responses">Respond 1</div>
    <div id="respond-2" class="responses" style="display: none" >Respond 2</div>
</div>
<button id="respond1Button">Respond 1</button>
<button id="respond2Button">Respond 2</button>
```

Below is the script to show/hide based on the corresponding button click,

```
$(function() {
    var $respond1 = $('#respond-1');
    var $respond2 = $('#respond-2');
    var $responses = $('.responses');

    $('#respond1Button').click(function() {
        $responses.hide();
        $respond1.show();
    });

    $('#respond2Button').click(function() {
        $responses.hide();
        $respond2.show();
    });
});
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/42qFr/)

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for something like this?

```
<div id="respond-1">First Response<div>
<div id="respond-2" style="display:none;">Second Response<div>

<button type="button" onclick="$('#respond-1').show();$('#respond-2').hide():">repond1Button</button>

<button type="button" onclick="$('#respond-2').show();$('#respond-1').hide():">repond2Button</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `.click` event to bind a click handler.  Elements that have IDs are selected using `$('#id')`, so combining those two you could easily create a button that makes a div visible.

```
<div id="respond-1"></div>
<button id="respond1Button">Show Respond 1</button>

// on DOM ready...
$(function() {
    // Select the divs
    var resp1 = $('#respond-1');

    // Hide them to start
    resp1.hide();

    // Bind click handlers
    $('#respond1Button').click(function() {
        resp1.show();
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Note that you cant have multiple itens with the same ID attribute, and the DIV tag doesn't have an attribute named NAME.

In this case, I suppose that the best option is to define a class 'respond-1' either to the BUTTON and the DIV. Than, depending the class of the button clicked, we show the correspondent DIV. (Sorry about any english mistake, its not my native language) :)

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $('button.respond-1, button.respond-2').click(function(){

        $('div.respond-1, div.respond-2').hide();
        $('div.' + $(this).attr('class')).show();

    });

});
```